# Is it possible to define and chain nested groups in LESS

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

I'd like to simplify the following CSS-rules:

```
.class > li > a:hover,
.class > li > span:hover,
.class > li > a:focus,
.class > li > span:focus,
.class > .active > a,
.class > .active > span,
.class > .active > a:hover,
.class > .active > span:hover,
.class > .active > a:focus,
.class > .active > span:focus {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

Having only

```
.class > li > a:hover,
.class > li > span:hover,
.class > li > a:focus,
.class > li > span:focus {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

would allow:

```
.class > li {
  > a:hover, > span:hover, > a:focus, > span:focus {
    background-color:#cccccc;
  }
}
```

But I also have the `.active`-group, with some other direct children. Can I also define and chain groups of nested elements, e.g.:

```
.class {
  > li {> a:hover, > span:hover, > a:focus, > span:focus},
  > .active {> a, > span, > a:hover, > span:hover, > a:focus, > span:focus}
  {
    background-color:#ccc;
  }
}
```

Comment: In Selectors 4 (once it is implemented within the next couple of years anyway), this could be simplified as `.class > li > :matches(a, span):matches(:hover, :focus), .class > .active > :matches(a, span):matches(*, :hover, :focus)`. (Side note, technically, `:matches(*, :hover, :focus)` is redundant in terms of matching elements because of the `*`, but it is not redundant in terms of specificity because of `:hover` and `:focus`.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `extend` like below to extend the properties and also combine the selectors.

```
.class {
    > li {
        > a:hover, > span:hover, > a:focus, > span:focus {
            background-color:#cccccc;
        }
    }
    > .active {
        > a, > span, > a:hover, > span:hover, > a:focus, > span:focus{
            &:extend(.class > li > a:hover);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the parameter to the `extend` function should have **a full selector path** like `.class > li > a:hover` and just `li > a:hover` or `a:hover` won't work.

---

Alternately, you could also use a separate ruleset for all the common props (like below) and use it in both places. Using this method would however add one extra selector (`.common-props`) in the compiled CSS but I guess one line should not make much difference.

```
.class {
    > li {
        > a:hover, > span:hover, > a:focus, > span:focus {
            &:extend(.common-props);
        }
    }
    > .active {
        > a, > span, > a:hover, > span:hover, > a:focus, > span:focus{
            &:extend(.common-props);
        }
    }
}

.common-props{
      background-color:#cccccc;
}
```

---

Or even **simpler** you can do like below (my personal preference is this):

```
.class {
    > li > a:hover, > li > span:hover, > li > a:focus, 
    > li > span:focus, > .active > a, > .active > span, 
    > .active > a:hover, > .active > span:hover,  
    > .active > a:focus, > .active > span:focus{
        background-color:#cccccc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, in this case the "flat" syntax seems to be the most simple already (and an attempt to bulbulate it via nesting can make it to be totally unreadable exactly because of `li` and `.active` difference). After all the selectors there are generic enough to never care of the repetition at all.